# Can we parse woocommerce cart key to get product added to cart time

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

```
[cart] => a:1:{s:32:"**c9f0f895fb98ab9159f51fd0297e236d**";a:10:{s:3:"key";s:32:"**c9f0f895fb98ab9159f51fd0297e236d**";s:10:"product_id";i:8;s:12:"variation_id";i:0;s:9:"variation";a:0:{}s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:13:"line_tax_data";a:2:{s:8:"subtotal";a:0:{}s:5:"total";a:0:{}}s:13:"line_subtotal";i:180;s:17:"line_subtotal_tax";i:0;s:10:"line_total";i:180;s:8:"line_tax";i:0;}}
```

In woocommerce session cart can the cart key be parsed to get product add to cart time or any other details from this key.

Comment: where come this string from ?

Comment: It is from woocommerce session table

Answer (score 0):

Details can be parsed from this cart key by using php unserialize function. You can view this function documentation here http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: I was taking about the string 'c9f0f895fb98ab9159f51fd0297e236d' can it be decoded to get the product added to cart time or any other details.